# MVC DisplayFor template table with duplicated headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Using a EditorFor template and trying to create a table, how can I get only one header row instead of one for each item of the collection?

Being the viewmodel

```
public class CashbackOfferViewModel
{
    public List<SingleCashbackOfferViewModel> Offers { get; set; }
}
```

In the view I have

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Offers)
```

And the display template is

```
@using LMS.MVC.Infrastructure
@model LMS.MVC.Areas.Finance.Models.SingleCashbackOfferViewModel
<table class="dataGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CampaignName)</th>  
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PersonId)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FullName)</ths>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CampaignName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PersonId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FullName)</td>          
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be:

Create display template for your whole model

```
@using LMS.MVC.Infrastructure
@model LMS.MVC.Areas.Finance.Models.CashbackOfferViewModel
<table class="dataGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <th>CampaignName</th>  
            <th>PersonId</th>
            <th>FullName</ths>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Offers.Count; ++i)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Offers[i].CampaignName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Offers[i].PersonId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Offers[i].FullName)</td>          
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also i think in your code, your model must be List of `SingleCashbackOfferViewModel` and you can easily iterate over the list and create table

Comment: Well, I was precisely thinking of this to get rid of the foreach in the view. Actually I can put the header in the main view (for the first item [0] for example) and just call the display template for the body, but I think is not ideal having them separated